# Trying to run python script for google scholar application

Tags: python

I need get the following information:

```
To Make a Google Scholar profile to estimate the number of 
citations per year from the graph plotted as part of the profile
```

from the script below:

```
http://infohost.nmt.edu/~borchers/scrapescholarcitecounts.py
```

Running the script I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapescholarcitecounts.py", line 56, in <module>
    chart=m.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Is the script out of date? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can try to contact with the script author?

Comment: Should check first if your `re.search` returns anything before assigning one of its groups to a variable(in this expression: `m=pchart.search(html)` )

Comment: I would not parse html with  regex